# discord.js v13 bot Joins voice channel but doesn't play anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, audio-player

I would like to code a music hadler which should be able to play music and sounds as mp3.

**Here is what i have planned:**

`musicPlayer.background("mp3 url", voicechannel)`
This should play a mp3 file in the background. If it is done playing it should start again. If this function is getting called again it should remove the old mp3 and play the new one. Volume: 0.5

`musicPlayer.playSound("mp3", voicechannel)`
This function should not remove the background music and play another mp3 on top the background music. This shouldn't get looped. Volume: 1.0

`musicPlayer.stop(voicechannel)`
This stops the music and sound and leaves the voicechannel.

**My code:**

```
const { createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, joinVoiceChannel, AudioPlayerStatus } = require('@discordjs/voice');

const audioPlayers = new Map();

async function playBackgroundMusic(url, voiceChannel) {
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: voiceChannel.id,
      guildId: voiceChannel.guild.id,
      adapterCreator: voiceChannel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
      volume: 0.5, // Set the volume here
    });
  
    const player = createAudioPlayer();
  
    const resource = createAudioResource(url, {
      inlineVolume: true,
    });
  
    player.play(resource);
  
    connection.subscribe(player);
  
    audioPlayers.set(voiceChannel.guild.id, player);
  
    connection.on('stateChange', (_, newState) => {
      if (newState.status === VoiceConnectionStatus.Disconnected) {
        audioPlayers.delete(voiceChannel.guild.id);
      }
    });
  
    player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
      player.play();
    });
  
    connection.on('debug', console.debug);
    connection.on('error', console.error);
  }
  
  async function playSoundEffect(url, voiceChannel) {
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: voiceChannel.id,
      guildId: voiceChannel.guild.id,
      adapterCreator: voiceChannel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
      volume: 1.0, // Set the volume here
    });
  
    const player = createAudioPlayer();
  
    const resource = createAudioResource(url, {
      inlineVolume: true,
    });
  
    player.play(resource);
  
    connection.subscribe(player);
  
    player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
      connection.destroy();
    });
  
    connection.on('debug', console.debug);
    connection.on('error', console.error);
  }

  async function stopAudio(voiceChannel) {
    const player = audioPlayers.get(voiceChannel.guild.id);
  
    if (player) {
      player.stop();
      const connection = player.state.subscription.connection;
      connection.destroy();
      audioPlayers.delete(voiceChannel.guild.id);
    }
  }

module.exports = {
  background: playBackgroundMusic,
  playSound: playSoundEffect,
  stop: stopAudio,
};
```

**THANKS A LOT FOR HELPING!**

I tried using different mp3 files. It joins the voice channel but does not play anything.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add this intent:

```
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES
```

my bad